# Dependent dropdown lists - autoload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two dependent dropdown lists: products and releases. When I change the product, the list of releases of this product reloads so that it lists releases only for the chosen product. I used 'change' method to load releases when the product is changed but when the page loads there were no releases listed for the default product. I couldn't select a release if there was only one product. To solve this I added an additional 'focus' method to overcome this but i still don't know how to make the releases load when the page loads.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#product").focus(function() {
        $.get('../deliveries/loadReleases.php?productName=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#release").html(data);
        }); 
    });

    $("#product").change(function() {
        $.get('../deliveries/loadReleases.php?productName=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("#release").html(data);
    }); 
  });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need of `focus`. You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#product").change(function() {
        $.get('../deliveries/loadReleases.php?productName=' + $(this).val(), function(data) {
            $("#release").html(data);
        }); 
    }).trigger("change");

});
```

It will trigger the `change` event immediately after attaching the handler.